# Laravel - Carbon - Errors parsing datetime to extract month

Tags: php, laravel, parsing, php-carbon

Need some help here.
Let me say that this might be very simple to answer, but i'm not a programmer and started doing an app with laravel without learning the basics of php.

So, i am using Carbon to parse a datetime, to extract the month in it, and i am getting some errors.
Here's what i want to parse:

```
 DB::table('task_interactions')->whereIn('task_id', $tasksKc)->pluck('created_at')
```

i'm doing it inside a query, like this:

```
->where(Carbon::parse(DB::table('task_interactions')->whereIn('task_id', $tasksKc)->pluck('created_at'))->month,'=', $december)
```

the error i got was:

```
Exception in Carbon.php line 291:
DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string ([&quot;2017-12-07 10:03:12&quot;,....
```

Did some search and found that the problem was the "" and i had to trim the string, like this:

```
where(Carbon::parse(trim(DB::table('task_interactions')->whereIn('task_id', $tasksKc)->pluck('created_at'),'"'))->month,'=', $december)
```

... and got the same error.
So, I've isolated the query to dd() it in the view, and still, i cannot understand what's wrong.
if i dd this in the view

```
$test = DB::table('task_interactions')->whereIn('task_id', $tasksKc)->pluck('created_at');
```

i get:

```
Collection {#460 ▼
  #items: array:657 [▼
    0 => "2017-12-07 10:03:12"
    1 => "2017-12-07 10:03:46"
    2 => "2017-12-07 10:04:20"
    3 => "2017-12-07 10:05:08"
    4 => "2017-12-07 10:06:29"
    5 => "2017-12-07 10:07:39"
    6 => "2017-12-07 10:09:58"
    7 => "2017-12-07 10:13:25"
    8 => "2017-12-07 10:13:57"
    9 => "2017-12-07 10:14:28"
    10 => "2017-12-07 10:15:10".....
```

and if i dd this:

```
$test = trim(DB::table('task_interactions')->whereIn('task_id', $tasksKc)->pluck('created_at'),'"');
```

i get:

```
"["2017-12-07 10:03:12","2017-12-07 10:03:46","2017-12-07 10:04:20","2017-12-07 10:05:08","2017-12-07 10:06:29","2017-12-07 10:07:39","2017-12-07 10:09:58","2017 ▶"
```

Any clues?

Thanks in advance

Comment: that's what i am trying to do. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this inside the query. Use the [`whereMonth()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#where-clauses) method instead:

```
->whereMonth('created_at', 12)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! For some reason i thought that whereMonth() only worked in date, not in datetime. it got my code simpler and solved the problem